# typescript: req.user is possibly 'undefined' - express and passport js

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, passport.js

I have a Node.js TypeScript authentication system that works using passport.

My problem is that when I use `req.user` in a route I get this error on `req.user`: `Object is possibly 'undefined'.`

This is a normal behavior of Typescript but I am using a middleware to protect routes that I want to use `req.user` in them and this way `req.user` cannot be undefined.

This is where I extend `Express.User` Type:

```
import { users } from "@prisma/client";

declare global {
    namespace Express {
        interface User extends users {}
    }
}
```

This is the middleware that I'm using to protect routes for logged in users:

```
export function checkIsAuthenticated(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
        if (!req.user) req.logOut();
        else return next();
    }
    res.status(400).json({
        errors: [{ message: "no user logged in" }],
    });
}
```

And this is the route for getting the user info:

```
export function userRoute(req: Request, res: Response) { // defining the route
    res.json({
        id: req.user.id,               // I'm getting the error in these 4 lines
        username: req.user.username,   //
        email: req.user.email,         //
        role: req.user.role,           //
    });
}

router.get("/user", checkIsAuthenticated, userRoute); // using the route
```

I don't want to check if user is defined because I don't want to do it in every route and that's not a good practice. That's why middleware is for.

I'm not good at Typescript so I need some help to fix it.

Comment: *"I don't want to check if user is defined because I don't want to do it in every route and that's not a good practice."* I wouldn't say that's bad practice. It would give you a nice explicit error if you left out the authentication middleware when creating one of these routes, for instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I don't want to check if user is defined because I don't want to do it in every route and that's not a good practice.

I'd quibble that there's nothing wrong with checking the request for a user and giving yourself a nice useful error message if you've accidentally used one of these handlers on a route that you forgot to put the authentication on. That would look like this:

```typescript
type RequestWithUser = Request & {user: typeOfUserObject};
function assertHasUser(req: Request): asserts req is RequestWithUser {
    if (!( "user" in req)) {
        throw new Error("Request object without user found unexpectedly");
    }
}
```

Then your handler for those routes:

```typescript
export function userRoute(req: Request, res: Response) {
    assertHasUser(req);
    // ...you can use `req.user` here...
});
```

[Playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBKkPIDMCqBnCAnOAjAVhAxsFALxQD2uBwA3AFC2zQBKEAjgK4QrADqAlsAAWqDCSgsOXIgDIoAb3Zp0ALhjgIiEZkqEAvnQTsAdoT5kjUAIYolwABLWtACnRtVEztwCUq67ZRQrqxQfAEeUvxCWvK0UHEhCFBOAIROUABEihjpIRZBXl4x8cUwguhkAO5QRhBVAKLo5ehO6eHc5DpEFQKCZOxEWehQCH1GACZQxhAAHpCEEGMANiDpXnTFurSbtIYmwGYWM5YAtmCLEC5u4myewIVysfF+GPaOSpesa49x+OYoZOcAHSLMgAcw+gMGX10QA)

(You can just use `asserts req is Request & {user: typeOfUserObject}` if you don't want a `RequestWithUser` type, but it's often useful to have an alias.)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! It would be great if express could detect that I'm checking a request property in a middleware for a request but I think it's the limitation of JS or TS at this time and we have to get around it for now.

Comment: If my route is async, should this check be done *inside* the `try/catch`?

Comment: @FlorianWalther - If you're passing an `async` function to `app.get`, `app.use`, etc., then it's important that the **entire** body of the function be wrapped in `try`/`catch` (with the `catch` sending an error response), since otherwise the promise the `async` function creates will just be ignored by Express, which pays no attention to the return value of a route function. That means an error in the `async` function becomes an unhandled rejection.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thank you. So programming errors inside route handlers should always be caught (and return 500) rather than exit the app?

Comment: @FlorianWalther - I think that's up to you, the author. But in general, you don't want your server process taken down by a bad request. (Whether you return a 500 or some other error is also a decision you'll want to make on a case-by-case basis.)

Comment: I really liked your solution. But now I have moved all my request body & param validation from the controller into a middleware as well and I'm wondering if I should use that assert function for all of these arguments. Seems a bit verbose.

Comment: @FlorianWalther - It's entirely up to you. I would probably include the assert for the reason I mentioned above: In case I forgot to add authentication to a route. But if you don't want to, you can use `RequestWithUser` as the type of `req` and then use a type assertion when registering the handler: `router.get("/user", checkIsAuthenticated, userRoute as (req: Request, res: Response) => void);` or any of several similar things that prevent the type error. I'd probably prefer the single function call in each route handler, but I've done relatively little (directly) with Express.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thank you for the tip! Does this have any benefit over casting the variable (user) directly? Because I also have a `file` field that's guaranteed by a middleware but possibly undefined for the compiler. And this file wouldn't be included in RequestWithUser.

Comment: @FlorianWalther - It's fundamentally the same. (Note that TypeScript doesn't have *casting*, it as [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions), which are different although the difference isn't important here.) But if you're going to have `const userReq = req as RequestWithUser;` in every handler and then use `userReq`, for me it's cleaner just to have the assertion function and just use `req` directly.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder That makes sense. Although I meant asserting the type of `req.user` and `req.file` (for example) and not the whole request object. 
I would like to use your approach, but how do I do that for different combinations of properties?
In my case, the `req.file` can also be "guaranteed" by a middleware. Can I create combinations of types to assert `req.user` AND `req.file` and `req.user` OR `req.file` (and maybe more combinations in the future)? Creating a RequestWithUserAndFile type seems awkward.

Comment: @FlorianWalther - I'm a big fan of wrapping things like `router.get` and such in this kind of situation. If you have multiple routes that require a user, or a file, or both, my approach would be to write wrappers like `getWithUser`, `getWithFile`, etc., then use those to set up the routes (including the middleware on them). [Something like this](https://tsplay.dev/mAJ1QW). Now, your middleware setup may be different (you may be applying it at the route*r* level rather than the route level), but you get the idea...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thank you for this code example and all your help! I'll try to implement it in my code!

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Your get wrappers won't have effect on the types if the controller is in another file, right?

Comment: @FlorianWalther - I don't quite understand the question. There's nothing file-specific about [the linked example](https://tsplay.dev/mAJ1QW). If you export `getWithuser` etc., you can import them into any file and use them to set up routes in that file.

Answer (score -1):

```js
export function userRoute(req: Request, res: Response) { // defining the route
    res.json({
        id: req.user!.id,               // you tell typescript that req.user for sure not. null
        username: req.user!.username,   //
        email: req.user!.email,         //
        role: req.user!.role,           //
    });
}

router.get("/user", checkIsAuthenticated, userRoute);
```

Comment: That will work, but best practice is to avoid those sorts of assertions.